# Java - Specific linked list serialization

Tags: java, serialization, linked-list, deserialization, structure

I have ListRand structure:

```
class ListRand
{
    public ListNode Head;
    public ListNode Tail;
    public int Count;

    public void Serialize(FileStream s)
    {
    }

    public void Deserialize(FileStream s)
    {
    }
}
```

Which is made of ListNodes:

```
class ListNode
{
    public ListNode Prev;
    public ListNode Next;
    public ListNode Rand; // random element in list
    public string Data;
}
```

The question is:
How to implement `Serialize` and `Deserialize` methods of `ListRand` with complexity better than O(N * N)

**UPDATE, thanks @HonzaZidek and @JoopEggen my final solution is (i didn't test it on real data)**

```
public class ListNode {
public ListNode prev;
public ListNode next;
public ListNode rand; // random element inside the list
public String data;
}


class ListRand {
public ListNode head;
public ListNode tail;
public int count;

public void serialize(FileOutputStream fileOutputStream) {

    // value is index of rand
    Map<ListNode, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    ListNode node = head;

    // assigning indexes for all ListNodes sequentially
    int index = 0;
    do {
        map.put(node, index);
        node = node.next;
        index++;

    } while (node != null);

    // iterate over map and write data and random index to fileOutputStream
    for (Map.Entry<ListNode, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {

        ListNode key = entry.getKey();
        ListNode rand = key.rand;

        String outputString = (rand == null) ?
                key.data + " " + "-1" + "\n" :
                key.data + " " + map.get(rand) + "\n";

        try {
            fileOutputStream.write(outputString.getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public ListRand deSerialize(FileInputStream fileInputStream) {

    ListRand result = new ListRand();
    ListNode head = new ListNode();
    result.head = head;

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream));
    String line;

    List<ListNode> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<>();
    ListNode current = head;

    try {

        // read data and create linked list structure - O(N) complexity
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] dataArray = line.trim().split(" ");
            String data = dataArray[0];
            Integer randomIndex = Integer.parseInt(dataArray[1]);

            ListNode next = new ListNode();
            current.next = next;
            current.data = data;

            next.prev = current;

            nodes.add(current);
            current = next;

            indexes.add(randomIndex);
        }

        // assign null to last node's next element
        ListNode lastNode = nodes.get(nodes.size() - 1);
        lastNode.next = null;

        // iterate over map and write data and random index to fileOutputStream - O(N) complexity
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++) {

            // get by index - O(1) complexity
            ListNode node = nodes.get(i);
            Integer randIndex = indexes.get(i);
            node.rand = (randIndex == -1) ? null : nodes.get(randIndex);
        }

        result.count = nodes.size();
        result.tail = nodes.get(nodes.size() - 1);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;
}
}
```

Comment: Linear browsing of a linked list should be O(N). What have you tried to suspect a O(N*N) complexity?

Comment: @SergeBallesta, I agree with you in case of simple LinkedArray , but here is one more element - ListNode.Rand. How to save reference to it?

Comment: Oups, did not pay enough attention to that... How do you want to serialize that for each node: `Rand` index or data? First will be simpler to read, second to write... In either case, if N is great enough, a HashMap data, index could help.

Comment: I suppose that you speak about **time** complexity when you require better than O(N\*N). Is your **memory** complexity limited? Then the hash map solution suggested by Serge may give you linear time complexity I believe. Or even less memory consuming would be if you are allowed to add a transient attribute *index* to `ListNode` - this attribute would be assigned and valid only just before the serialization :)

Answer (score 2):

I can see some possibilities how to achieve O(N) time complexity. In both the cases, you just serialize the list as a sequence of tuples (Data, index of the random node).

1. As Serge Ballesta suggests in his comment, read all the nodes and create a hash map, with an initial capacity big enough, mapping `ListNode`s to *index*. This will be linear if the hash code is well designed and if you do not have a very bad luck (not much probable).

   If your `ListNode` does not have `hashCode()` and `equals()` defined, you will create a wrapper class with `ListNode` as its only attribute as use this as the key in the map. However, because you always consider two instances of `ListNode` as *not* equal, it will *practically* work also with the default implementation of `equals()` and `hashCode()`, as their "normal" implementation of `hashCode()` will be good enough. although it is not strictly required by the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--):

> As much as is reasonably practical, the `hashCode` method defined by class Object does return distinct integers for distinct objects. (The `hashCode` may or may not be implemented as some function of an object's memory address at some point in time.)

2. If you are allowed to add an attribute to `ListNode` - add *index*. This attribute would be assigned and valid only just before the serialization. Just before the serialization, lock the list, iterate though it and assign each node its index. This will consume less memory than the hash map and will be deterministically linear.

Answer (score 2):

From **Head** serialize all **Next**. Then (having all nodes) from **Head** serialize all **Rand** as a reference (for instance an index no).

- First Head+Nexts loop `O(N)`
- Then mapping Rand: `O(N.log N)` as lookup of one node is log N.
- Entirely `O(N.log N)`

You should have realized as much. The implementation I leave to you, as this seems some CS course task.

Comment: Mapping `Rand` can be done in O(N): 1. Create `HashMap(ListNode, index)` - if you do not have very bad luck and/or bad hash code, it is O(N). 2. Now you can search for each node's index in the hash map - again it's linear, unless you have a very bad luck.

Comment: @HonzaZidek indeed, of course leaving the implementation open to the OP's desire, I was a bit conservative. Everything is possible. A yukkie alternative: One even might number all Head/Next nodes in the first run abusing the Data field to store it. Then on the second run, Rand.Data would give the index number. (Please do not downvote me for this "short-cut.")

Comment: I will not downvote your answer for it. Please do not downvote mine either - I suggested exactly the "yukkie alternative" to number all nodes in the first run. I do not find it especially yukkie and the OP did not explicitly forbid it :)

Comment: @HonzaZidek I just became aware of your answer, +1, it is adequate (as I would do it). Maybe a bit _too_ helpful for teaching.

Comment: @HonzaZidek, I suppose i should extend ListNode and ovverride hashCode, before creating HashMap, othervise i couldn't find equal ListNodes.

Comment: @JoopEggen, I can't change these classes, I can't change data value

Comment: @HasaDev As for the `hashCode()` and `equals()` issue, see edit of my answer.